# Delta rule for binary step function

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, perceptron, neural-computing

I have a question of understanding about the Delta Rule:

$\Delta w_i = (y - \hat{y}) \times x_i$

Why does $x$ have to be multiplied again after the difference? If the input is $0$, the product of $w$ and $x$ remains $0$ anyway. Then, it should not matter if the weight changes with an input of $0$.

Let us take the following example:

- $w_i$ = the ith weight of the weight vector
- $\Delta w_i$ = the change in weight $w_i$
- $y$ = the desired output of the neuron for the learning example
- $\hat{y}$ = the actual, calculated output for the learning example
- $x_i$ = the input

Step $t$:

- Input $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
- Random weights = $\begin{bmatrix} 0.1 & 0.1 & 0.1 \end{bmatrix}$
- Scalar product $\to 0.1$
- Step function outputs $1 \to \hat{y} = 1$

BUT we want as output $y = 0$ 
So the weights have to be adjusted as follows:

Step $t+1$:

- $\Delta w_0 = (0 - 1) \times 1 = -1$
- $\Delta w_1 = (0 - 1) \times 0 = 0$
- $\Delta w_2 = (0 - 1) \times 0 = 0$

$w_i^{new} = w_i^{old} + \Delta w_i$

- New weights: $ \begin{bmatrix} -0.9 & 0.1 & 0.1 \end{bmatrix}$
- Scalar product = $-0.9$
- Output $(y = 0)$

You can totally skip the multiplication by $x$, can't you? 
Because at the latest when the scalar product is created, the weight which is multiplied by $x = 0$ is still not included. 
So why multiply by $x$ in $\Delta w$?

Comment: What's the Delta Rule?  I suspect you might be more likely to get an answer if you add more context.

Comment: If you're asking about backpropagation, I suggest writing down the loss function and then computing its gradient with respect to $w_i$ and checking what gradient descent will do.